# Connect to Amazon AWS Server via SFTP Net Drive?

Tags: networking, ssh, sftp, amazon-ec2, windows-server

I'm trying to connect to Amazon ec2 windows server via [SFTP Net Drive](http://cdn.nsoftware.com/help/NDC/app/default.htm) - however I keep getting various errors.

1. Connection error 10061
2. Connection timeout

I did tons of research on both errors and I completely disabled firewall on local machine and remote server but this did not solve the problem. I also modified security group to allow all kinds of traffic (SSH + RDP + All traffic) in AWS console but this did not resolve the problem either. I tried connecting with different ports (22, 3389, 21) and opening all ports on remote server which did nothing.

By now I'm running out of options. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you ssh in? Have you set up certificate authentication on your "net drive" software? You haven't given any configuration or diagnostic information so it's difficult to help you.